# Pass NSArrays from ViewController to NSObject class

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsarray, core-plot

I have a single view application where the ViewController contains a UIView of custom class `CPTGraphHostingView` so that it holds a CorePlot graph. The content of that UIView is managed by an NSObject sub-class called `SimpleScatterPlot`. This `SimpleScatterPlot` object holds all the parameters needed to configure the graph (axis ranges, labels, number of points, etc.)

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h"
#import "SimpleScatterPlot.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet CPTGraphHostingView *_graphHostingView;
    SimpleScatterPlot *_scatterPlot;   
    NSMutableData *dataConexion;
}

@property (nonatomic,strong) NSArray *valor;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSArray *strAnoMes;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSArray *indicador;
@property (nonatomic, retain) SimpleScatterPlot *scatterPlot;

@end
```

In ViewController.m I have some methods to initialise a few arrays from some JSON data:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize indicador,valor,strAnoMes;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

    NSString *urlString = @"http://xxxx/ios/datosgrafica.php";

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    (void)[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];   
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    dataConexion = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)theData
{
    [dataConexion appendData:theData];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

    indicador = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataConexion options:nil error:nil];

    // ARRAYS OF INTEREST
    strAnoMes = [indicador valueForKey:@"StrAnoMes"];
    valor = [indicador valueForKey:@"Valor"];

    self.scatterPlot = [[SimpleScatterPlot alloc] initWithHostingView:_graphHostingView andData:pointArray];
    [self.scatterPlot initialisePlot];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    UIAlertView *errorView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"The download could not complete - please make sure you're connected to either 3G or Wi-Fi." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [errorView show];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
}
```

In the `SimpleScatterPlot.m` I would like to use the array "`valor`" to configure axis ranges, and I would like to use the array "`strAnoMes`" to draw custom labels in the xAxis.

What do I have to do so that I can pass those arrays defined in ViewController to SimpleScatterPlot?

I have tried to `#import "ViewController.h"` but it gives me errors. Any other ideas? What is the best way to approach this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take two properties in  SimpleScatterPlot.

SimpleScatterPlot.h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray * strAnoMes;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray * valor;
```

SimpleScatterPlot.m

```
@synthesize strAnoMes;
@synthesize valor;
```

In ViewController.m, After creating scatterPlot in connectionDidFinishLoading:,  assign the values to above properties as below.

```
self.scatterPlot.strAnoMes = strAnoMes;
self.scatterPlot.valor = valor;
```

Comment: I'm doing what you suggested, but the arrays in SimpleScatterPlot are coming up empty.

Comment: Did you log the values while assigning arrays to SimpleScatterPlot.

Comment: Nevermind! I had just placed the code a couple of lines above the creation of scatterPlot.. Problem solved! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to create a simple data object and pass it directly into your `SimpleScatterPlot` object:

Data Object:

```
@interface SimpleScatterPlotData : NSObject
@property (...) NSArray *valor;
@property (...) NSArray *strAnoMes;
@end

@implementaton SimpleScatterPlotData
@synthesize valar;
@synthesize strAnoMes;
-(void)dealloc
{
   ...
   ...
   [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Implement a load method in your `SimpleScatterPlot` class:

```
@interface SimpleScatterPlot
-(void)loadData:(SimpleScatterPlotData *)data;
@end

@implementation SimpleScatterPlot
-(void)loadData:(SimpleScatterPlotData *)data
{
    NSArray *valor = data.valor;
    NSArray *strAnoMes = data.strAnoMes;
    /*
      Do something
    */
}
@end
```

Then in your `ViewController` class:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
    indicador = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataConexion options:nil error:nil];

    // ARRAYS OF INTEREST
    strAnoMes = [indicador valueForKey:@"StrAnoMes"];
    valor = [indicador valueForKey:@"Valor"];

    SimpleScatterPlotData *data = [[[SimpleScatterPlotData alloc] init] autorelease];
    data.valor = valor;'
    data.strAnoMes = strAnoMes;

    self.scatterPlot = [[SimpleScatterPlot alloc] initWithHostingView:_graphHostingView andData:pointArray];
    [self.scatterPlot loadData:data];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also change your current initializer or add a new initializer to your SimpleScatterPlot class so that you pass those arrays in when you alloc the object. So your the call to your initializer would look something like:

```
self.scatterPlot = [[SimpleScatterPlot alloc] initWithHostingView:_graphHostingView andData:pointArray andValor:valor andstrAnoMes:strAnoMes];
```

Then in your initializer you can set the object properties to those passed in values.